# Regular Expression to match ranges of numbers except some certain ranges of numbers and some particular numbers

Tags: regex, numeric

I am creating a user security policy for each user. Each user security policy will have a regular expression statement in it.

Each webpage has its own unique ID in numeric format ranging from 0 to 100000. When a user accesses a webpage, the system will check the webpage's ID against the user's security policy expressing in regular expression.

For instance, a user has the access to all webpages (ID ranging from 1 - 100000) except webpages with ID number 2, 54, **109 to 2001** and 10521. How can I write an efficient regular expression to tackle this requirement?

Comment: It is a better thing to check by a actual programming language. Just get the user ID as any number and check if it is in range with the usual `if`. It will be much cleaner and shorter.

Comment: To illustrate just why regular expressions are not the correct tool for this task, the regex for the example you suggested would be `^(?!(2|54|109|1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2}|1\d{3}|200[01]|10521)$)(\d{1,5}|100000)$`.  This is before performance optimizations (efficiency criterion) like atomic groupings that will complicate the expression further.  And since it serves a security function, canonicalization vulnerabilities (e.g., leading zeros) will be a potential concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find this will be both a programmatic nightmare to maintain and a significant performance overhead to accomplish the task. You would likely find it much more effective (and less cumbersome) to work with lists instead. You could store these lists in a database, or even using a cloud service provider that communicates with a RESTful [api](/questions/tagged/api) and [json](/questions/tagged/json).

An example, written in php (mostly pseudo code), assuming the permissions have already been retrieved from the data storage:

```
//user1 is logged in and has access to the following array of allowed pages:
$loggedInUserPerms = array(1,6,99,821,983255);
if (in_array($pageID, $loggedInUserPerms))
{
    //the logged in user has access to this page
}
else
{
    //the logged in user doesn't, display access denied error
}
```

You could even expand this principle and use multidimensional arrays:

```
$loggedInUserPerms = array(
    1=>array("read"),
    6=>array("read","write"),
    9=>array("read","write"),
    821=>array("read","write","delete"),
    983255=>array("read")
);
if (in_array($pageID, $loggedInUserPerms))
{
    //the logged in user has access to this page

    //you can now handle the sub arrays as well 
    //to determine what level of access the user has.
}
else
{
    //the logged in user doesn't, display access denied error
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I am pretty new to regexp and thought it was the right tool for this. I will implement the security policy in list data structure as you recommended.

Comment: Good luck! There is a lot of information out there on regex -- while it's powerful, you'll find people often turn to it without understanding the purpose or programmatic overhead of using it where performance matters.